# Facebook ui dialog - "Share to wall" missing

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm making a FB app which should allow the user to share something on their wall or to the wall of a friend using Javascript SDK. The first part is fine seemingly, but not the second. The drop-down to choose on which wall the post will appear is missing. I couldn't find a option for this, I can only assume it has been removed from the API as it is possible from FB own interface. I can use the "Facebook sharer" but on some browsers the pop ups are blocked.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

To publish in a friend's wall you need stream_publish permission for both friends (the user and his friend must be users of the app and granted you permissions) and you have to do a POST request to the feed of the friend:

```
$config = array('link' => 'yoururl.com',
                      'message' => 'message',
                      'picture' => 'feed.jpg',
                      'name' => 'name',
                      'caption' => 'caption');

$ret_obj = $this->facebook->api('/'.$friend_id.'/feed', 'POST', $config);
```

You can do the POST request through AJAX but I'm afraid that there is no facebook JS dialog for this action.